# When would you us Ext.application() vs. Ext.Loader.setConfig, .require, and .onReady?

Tags: extjs4

I see that some of the examples included with ExtJS 4 start up via a single call to `Ext.application()`. Other examples, however, manually call `Ext.Loader.setConfig()`, `Ext.require()`, and `Ext.onReady()` instead. I want to make sure I understand the difference.

Am I correct in assuming that:

1. you'd normally use the convenient `Ext.application()` call for a full-screen (e.g., Viewport-based) app?
2. if you just want to use a few ExtJS components on a pre-existing "non-Ext" page you'd opt for the manual calls to `Ext.Loader`, `require`, and `onReady()`?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full application call is used for the Ext MVC approach, and comes with a set of conventions to pre-load additional components, for example the stores and views options in the controller classes. For a better explanation see the Ext documentation on [MVC](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture).

If you just need to throw a few components on the page, as you state, you will get better performance just using the loader, or better, avoiding dynamic loading (at least in production).